# find Sum of Sub-Query

Tags: mysql

Query need to find a client named Yossi Cohen, who purchased a number of items and the amount billed(sum) of purchase
For example: Yossi Cohen bought three items costing 40 shekels and we want to know the amount of the order.

example:

```
namecustomer  namemodel  quantity  sum
Yossi Cohen    iphone6      3      120
```

I try to write this:(not working)

```
SELECT nameCustomer,
   (SELECT idCustomer,nameCustomer,nameModel,idOrders,Quantity,
   SUM(price*Quantity)AS OrderTotal
   FROM Customers,OrdersItems,Products GROUP BY idOrders)
FROM Customer
 where Customer = 'Yossi Cohen';
```

Comment: I cannot test here but one first tip: you want to select by customer first (filter) then sum. The other way around is going to be too time consuming

Comment: The fact that your sub query is using implicit joins (which you shouldn't) without joining criteria in the where clause is going to be ... a problem. Also I'm not convinced you need a subquery

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```
SELECT idCustomer,nameCustomer,nameModel,idOrders,Quantity
From Customer
Where sum=price*Quantity 
AND   Customer = 'Yossi Cohen';
```